# How to read if FormControl checkbox is checked

Tags: angular, typescript, form-control

I have two inputs. One is a checkbox and the other is an autocomplete input. When the checkbox is checked, I Want to read from the autocomplete input. When the checkbox is not checked, I want to run code without reading from the input.

However, when I try to read from the checkbox, the value is always null and dirty is always false even if I click the checkbox and then hit submit. How do I grab the checkbox value here?

Here is the HTML

```
<mat-checkbox #checkbox [formcontrolname]="cbAddVestingOption" style="padding-bottom: 200px;">Add Vesting Option</mat-checkbox>
                <mat-form-field *ngIf="checkbox.checked" style="width: 600px">
                  <div>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Vesting Option" matInput formcontrolname="vestedoptions" [matAutocomplete]="auto" class="uppercase" />
                    <mat-error *ngIf="!isFreeTextValid">{{this.freeTextErrorMessage}}</mat-error>
                    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of vestedOptions" [value]="option" (onSelectionChange)="selected($event)">
                        {{option}}
                      </mat-option>
                    </mat-autocomplete>
                  </div>
                </mat-form-field>
```

In my typescript code, I add the checkbox to the formgroup in init() and then in submit() I check the value of the checkbox

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.vestedOptionsDetailForm = new FormGroup({
      vestedoptions: new FormControl(null, Validators.maxLength(30)),
      cbAddVestingOption: new FormControl(null)
    })
}

submit() {
    if (this.vestedOptionsDetailForm.controls["cbAddVestingOption"].value == "true") {
      this.downloadEOPIVestedOption();
    }
    else {
      this.downloadEOPI();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please check the solution now.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `[formcontrolname]="cbAddVestingOption"` to `formControlName="cbAddVestingOption"`.

Also another change, `== "true"` to `== true`.

Working demo at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-jmbq9e?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Video: https://giphy.com/gifs/7Hb3m0rvB9Zj5juUwd

Comment: Did you check the submit method?

Comment: That console logs the value of checkbox, true or false.

Comment: Kindly check the gif. It may help.

Comment: It works on stackblitz but does not work in my solution.